# How to aggregate duplicate timestamps with pandas?

Tags: python, indexing, time-series, pandas

I am working on python (`pandas` specifically) to analyze a dataset. (Python is too awesome, the power of open source is amazing). I am having trouble with a specific part of my dataset.

I have the following data set,

```
time,contract,ticker,expiry,strike,quote,price,volume
08:01:08,C,PXA,20100101,4000,A,57.8,60
08:01:11,C,PXA,20100101,4000,A,58.4,60
08:01:12,C,PXA,20100101,4000,A,58,60
08:01:16,C,PXA,20100101,4000,A,58.4,60
08:01:16,C,PXA,20100101,4000,A,58,60
08:01:21,C,PXA,20100101,4000,A,58.4,60
08:01:21,C,PXA,20100101,4000,A,58,60
```

and it goes on ...

I am using pandas to load the data. After this, I would like to be able to do the following, take a volume weighted average of the time there are duplicates.

i.e. since there are two asks at time 08:01:16, I would like to calculate the average price based on volume which would be (58.4*60 + 58*60)/(60+60) and an average of the volume on the volume column which would be (60+60)/2.

Comment: How do you read the data? Pandas usually does not accept duplicates in index.

Comment: i used pds.read_csv, it had no problem reading the data. What it did was it made my first column the date and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
In [28]: a = pd.read_csv('aa.csv')

In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
       time contract ticker    expiry  strike quote  price  volume
0  08:01:08        C    PXA  20100101    4000     A   57.8      60
1  08:01:11        C    PXA  20100101    4000     A   58.4      60
2  08:01:12        C    PXA  20100101    4000     A   58.0      60
3  08:01:16        C    PXA  20100101    4000     A   58.4      60
4  08:01:16        C    PXA  20100101    4000     A   58.0      60
5  08:01:21        C    PXA  20100101    4000     A   58.4      60
6  08:01:21        C    PXA  20100101    4000     A   58.0      60

In [30]: pd.DataFrame([{'time': k,
                        'price': (v.price * v.volume).sum() / v.volume.sum(),
                        'volume': v.volume.mean()}
                       for k,v in a.groupby(['time'])],
                      columns=['time', 'price', 'volume'])
Out[30]: 
       time  price  volume
0  08:01:08   57.8      60
1  08:01:11   58.4      60
2  08:01:12   58.0      60
3  08:01:16   58.2      60
4  08:01:21   58.2      60
```

Comment: i am trying to add back in the strike and contract columns back into the dataframe. however, because v.ticker returns both the position in the dataframe and the ticker itself, it is not adding correctly.

i wrote: 
pds.DataFrame(['time':k, 'price':(v.price*v.volume).sum()/v.volume.sum(),'volume':volume.mean(), 'ticker':v.ticker, 'strike':v.strike)} for k,v in a.groupby(['time'])], columns=['time','price','volume','ticker','strike'])

Comment: @user1449148 - you have to aggregate them somehow. Try with `'ticker':v.ticker.max(), 'strike':v.strike.max()`, which returns the same value if both original values are identical.

Comment: thank you again eumiro. i have now learned something useful about groupby

Comment: For larger datasets, aggregating with pivot_table is faster. In this case, you have to create a new column for 'price * volume' first, since each row can only be aggregated separately.